# Spring Boot maven exec - unable to start class

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception, exec-maven-plugin

In my maven build I want to run an application during the `package` phase and then have the integration tests run that require that application to be running.

However, I get this error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext`

I am using Spring Boot, so the class that has the main method is this:
package main;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>UserRegistrationServices</name>
    <description>RESTful API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>main.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To deploy to external servlet container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Spring Boot testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For returning objects as JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To decode Base64 data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To resolve a minor problem in logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-execution</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies> -->
                    <mainClass>main.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here is the full stack trace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building UserRegistrationServices 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ rest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ rest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ rest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.5:war (default-war) @ rest ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [rest] in [C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\target\rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [251 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\target\rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ rest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (my-execution) @ rest ---
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)

[main.Application.main()] INFO main.Application - Starting Application on CNU43390VX with PID 22552 (C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices\target\classes started by pmandayam in C:\Users\pmandayam\git\UserRegistrationServices)
[main.Application.main()] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3e975e24: startup date [Tue Aug 04 14:29:40 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[main.Application.main()] INFO org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/git/UserRegistrationServices/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.5/mongo-java-driver-2.12.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.6.3.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.9.3.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.4/jackson-core-2.5.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson-xml-databind/0.6.2/jackson-xml-databind-0.6.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.2/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.2/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.2/jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.0/stax2-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.12/slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/pmandayam/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar]
[main.Application.main()] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
[main.Application.main()] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3e975e24: startup date [Tue Aug 04 14:29:40 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[main.Application.main()] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3e975e24: startup date [Tue Aug 04 14:29:40 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[main.Application.main()] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3e975e24: startup date [Tue Aug 04 14:29:40 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.301 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-04T14:29:41-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/266M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (my-execution) on project rest: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: javax/servlet/ServletContext: javax.servlet.ServletContext -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had to add this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exec:java` plugin [does not handle provided dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418414/maven-exec-plugin-cant-depend-on-provided-dependancy) unless the `classpathScope` property is set to `compile`

(Unrelated but you may want to use `spring-boot:start` and `spring-boot:stop` to [run integration tests with Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/maven-plugin/usage.html))